# 2 identical file, how to build a template / component in Vue.js 2

Tags: templates, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using **Vue.js 2.0**, and I have this exact same code in 2 differents files, the only thing that changes is the *ID_SPECIFIC_TO_THIS_BLOCK* so I am a beginner about Vue and I was wondering if there was an way to implement a kind of template that I would be able to reuse for my 2 files

You can find bellow the entire code for one file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <hp-row>
                <hp-column>
                    <component v-for="component in content.column" :data="component" :key="component.id" :is="getComponentIdentifier(component.is)"></component>
                </hp-column>
            </hp-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModularView from '@/views/ModularView'

export default {
    name: 'AboutUsView',
    mixins: [ModularView],

    created () {
        this.fetch('blocks/ID_SPECIFIC_TO_THIS_BLOCK')
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use props:

```
export default {
    name: 'AboutUsView',
    mixins: [ModularView],
    props: ['ID_SPECIFIC_TO_THIS_BLOCK']
    created () {
        this.fetch(`blocks/${this.ID_SPECIFIC_TO_THIS_BLOCK}`)
    },
}

<about-us-view ID_SPECIFIC_TO_THIS_BLOCK="123"></about-us-view>
<about-us-view ID_SPECIFIC_TO_THIS_BLOCK="789"></about-us-view>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for you answer, I am sorry but I don't understand, why are you using HTML into the <script> ?

Comment: i'm not using html in the script but just showing when you use that component how you can pass the props.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a beginner and you don't use any further explanations or sources in your answer so you are probably doing right but I don't understand it

Comment: @Ced refer to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html and pay special attention to the section "*Passing Data to Child Components with Props*".

Comment: Can I please have a working exemple of it ? I tryed it but nothing works, the code of @Bhojendra Rauniyar is not clear for me