# Vue is there a way to pass data from route to component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Vue.js 2.0, and I have this exact same code in 2 differents files, so I decided to build only one component and redirect the 2 routes on it, then I just need to pass the ID to the route, this way my 2 components can display differents resultats.

Note: the only thing that changes is the ID **dsgh151rhj12t1j5j** I would like that each route can send it own ID to my *PageContentfulView* component

EDIT: I just want to pass data from Route to the component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <hp-row>
                <hp-column>
                    <component v-for="component in content.column" :data="component" :key="component.id" :is="getComponentIdentifier(component.is)"></component>
                </hp-column>
            </hp-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModularView from '@/views/ModularView'

export default {
    name: 'PageContentfulView',
    mixins: [ModularView],

    created () {
        this.fetch('blocks/dsgh151rhj12t1j5j')
    },
}
</script>
```

Routes:

```
    {
        path: '/satisfaction-guarantee',
        name: 'SatisfactionView',
        component: load('PageContentfulView'),
    },
    {
        path: '/about-us',
        name: 'AboutUsView',
        component: load('PageContentfulView'),
    },
```

Comment: Inside of the component you have `this.$route` with useful information such as `this.$route.name` https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 identical file, how to build a template / component in Vue.js 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426690/2-identical-file-how-to-build-a-template-component-in-vue-js-2)

Comment: It is not a duplicate I'm not asking the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'props' can solve your problem.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <hp-row>
                <hp-column>
                    <component v-for="component in content.column" :data="component" :key="component.id" :is="getComponentIdentifier(component.is)"></component>
                </hp-column>
            </hp-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModularView from '@/views/ModularView'

export default {
    name: 'PageContentfulView',
    mixins: [ModularView],
    props: ['id'],
    created () {
        this.fetch('blocks/' + this.id)
    },
}
</script>
```

**route**

```
  {
    path: '/satisfaction-guarantee',
    name: 'SatisfactionView',
    component: load('PageContentfulView'),
    props: { id: 'dsgh151rhj12t1j5j' },
},
{
    path: '/about-us',
    name: 'AboutUsView',
    component: load('PageContentfulView'),
    props: { id: 'blablablabla' },
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have the following error: 'id' is not defined (no-undef) at src/views/PageContentfulView.vue:21:32:
  19 |     props: ['id'],

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you a lot for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). You just need to include the parameter on the definition of the route, like below:

```
{
    path: '/satisfaction-guarantee/:ID',
    name: 'SatisfactionView',
    component: load('PageContentfulView'),
}
```

Inside you component, to access the `ID`, you just need to use the `this.$route.params.ID`.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, but the ID is a bit secret I would like to hide it from the user, so exposing it in the URL can expose the website to some security issue, do you have an Idea on how can I hide it ?

Comment: Then you could use the [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), that is made for sharing state in you application. When you want to change the `ID`, you change the state in the vuex store and your app does what it needs. Isn't easy as the dynamic routing, but, works as you need.

Answer (score 0):

### [Passing props to route component](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) allows an object mode.

[Example from the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/promotion/from-newsletter', component: Promotion, props: { newsletterPopup: false } }
  ]
})
```

### [Route meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

Also you always can use the `meta` property to pass extra data (like a `requireAuth` flag)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/test', component: TestComponent, meta: { someBoolean: false } }
  ]
})
```

And you can access it within your component

```
created() {
  let meta = this.$route.meta;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I pass my IDs as data instead of a boolean ?

Comment: I used a boolean to simplify the example, you can pass an object or any data type

Comment: exactly, and then in getComponentIdentifier do the magic to check that id

Answer (score 0):

Set the props in your route to `true` and place `/:id` at the end of your `path`

```
  const router = new VueRouter({
       routes: [
        { path: '/promotion/from-newsletter/:id',
          component: Promotion, 
          props: true
          }
          ]
        })
```

You can now extract the param `id` of your route from the props in the corresponding component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <hp-row>
                <hp-column>
                    <component v-for="component in content.column" :data="component" :key="component.id" :is="getComponentIdentifier(component.is)"></component>
                </hp-column>
            </hp-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ModularView from '@/views/ModularView'

export default {
    name: 'PageContentfulView',
    mixins: [ModularView],
    props: ['id'],
    created () {
        this.fetch('blocks/'+id)
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Excuse me, where do you Set the Id in the code you made ? I mean where do you say ID = dsgh151rhj12t1j5j ?

Comment: In your url, so `localhost:8080/promotion/from-newsletter/dsgh151rhj12t1j5j `, for example

Comment: I am sorry, I don't thing this is the best solution as I don't want the users to know the ID, I can't display it in the URL for privacy purposes